# How can I make directory writable?

Tags: macos, terminal

How can I make a directory writable, from the OS X terminal?

Comment: I recommend https://superuser.com/questions/52598/how-to-recursively-change-sharing-permission-of-a-folder-in-mac-os-x/229029#229029  for anyone that wants to do that in OS X _not_ using the terminal.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`chmod 777 <directory>`

This will give you execute/read/write privileges.  You can play with the numbers to finely tune your desired permissions.

Here is the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) with great examples.

Comment: It is a bad practice to simply make directories readable, writable, and executable if they do not need to be. @samoz answer is a more appropriate action.

Comment: @Tom - fair enough, but I explain that you can adjust the numbers to meet your requirements which additional docs on the topic.

Answer (score 123):

- `chmod  +w <directory>` or `chmod a+w <directory>` - Write permission for user, group and others
- `chmod u+w <directory>` - Write permission for user
- `chmod g+w <directory>` - Write permission for group
- `chmod o+w <directory>` - Write permission for others

Comment: Thanks for the specifics instead of doing blanket 777. I was doing `sudo chmod +w <dir>` and it wasn't working - but `a+w` worked.

Answer (score 112):

```
chmod +w <directory>
```

Answer (score 38):

To make the parent directory as well as all other sub-directories writable, just add -R

```
chmod -R a+w <directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
chmod 777 <directory>
```

this not change all ,just one file

```
chmod -R a+w <directory>
```

this ok

Answer (score -3):

Execute at Admin privilege using `sudo` in order to avoid permission denied
(Unable to change file mode) error.

```
sudo chmod 777 <directory location>
```

Comment: this gives full access to that folder which can be a security risk