# NEO4J 4.4 how to fix read-only error exporting db to csv file with apoc

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to export my entire neo4j db to a csv file using apoc like so:

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.all(“filename.csv", {})
```

with the following flags set in neo4j.conf

```
dbms.directories.plugins=plugins
dbms.directories.import=import

dbms.read_only=false
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=jwt.security.*,apoc.*

apoc.import.file.use_neo4j_config=false
apoc.export.file.enabled=true
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Failed to invoke procedure: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: fileName.csv (read-only file system)
```

So I am assuming I missed a flag. I would appreciate some help in fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the export directory is writable for Neo4J?

Comment: how do I do that?....

Comment: It depends: If you are on a *nix System: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070216/how-can-i-make-directory-writable